# How can we convert a string to be used as a number and reversible?

Tags: c++

I am building a code that takes a string of month and I want to increase this month using overloading so that I could get February.

Well, I tried to use switch case statement to convert month into numbers like 1 to 12, I increased that values but now I need another switch case to convert numbers to string again.

```
class DayOfYear
{
    private:
        int day;
        string month;
    public:
        DayOfYear(){}
        DayOfYear(int d, string m){
            day = d;
            month = m;
            if(d > 31 && d < 1){
                cout<<"Invalid input."<<endl;
            }
        }

        string check()           //To check the month 
        {
            switch(month)
            {
                case "January":
                    return 1;
                    break;
                case "February":
                    return 2";
                    break;
                case "March":
                    return 3;
                                        break;

                                // similarly upto november


                case "December":
                    return 12;
                    break;
                default:
                    cout<<"Invalid Input.";
                    break;
            }
        }

        DayOfYear operator++(){
            DayOfYear d;
            d.day = day++;
            if(d.day>31){
                d.day = 1;
                                ++d.month;

            }
        }
```

I dont expect ans, I am expecting methods.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It's hard to suggest anything useful with bits and pieces of uncompilable code.

Comment: Read about `boost::bimap`

Comment: So your program is expecting the input "January" and you wish to print out "February", and similarly if you get "June" you should print out "July"? And for "December"... "January"?

Comment: Could possible be a job for [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), or [std::pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair). Never heard of a `boost::bimap` before, but that also sounds promising.

Comment: What if the month is December and you want to increase it by 1?  What would the month be?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Probably January. In the thirteen month calendar Sol is month 7, right after Leap Day.

Comment: @user4581301 I know -- I wanted the OP to verify if they thought this through, since I see `++d.month` in the code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  if December 31 is entered then it should return January 1 which is of next year... Similarly, if January 1 is input then output should be December 31 of previous year

Answer (score 1):

You can't switch on a std::string in C++. It seems you are wanting to do something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <map>

const char* intAsMonth(int index)
{
  if(index < 1 || index > 12)
    return "invalid";

  const char* const months[] = { 
     "january",
     "february",
     "march",
     "april",
     "may",
     "june",
     "july",
     "august",
     "september",
     "october",
     "november",
     "december"
   };
   return months[index - 1];
}

int monthAsInt(std::string month)
{
  // make lower case
  std::transform(month.begin(), month.end(), month.begin(),
    [](char c){ return std::tolower(c); });

  static std::map<std::string, int> months = { 
     {"january", 1},
     {"february", 2},
     {"march", 3},
     {"april", 4},
     {"may", 5},
     {"june", 6},
     {"july", 7},
     {"august", 8},
     {"september", 9},
     {"october", 10},
     {"november", 11},
     {"december", 12}
   };
   auto it = months.find(month);
   if(it == months.end())
     return -1; // did not find
   return it->second;
 }

 int nextMonth(int month)
 {
   if(++month > 12) month = 1;
   return month;
 }

 int prevMonth(int month)
 {
   if(--month < 1) month = 12;
   return month;
 }

 std::string nextMonth(const std::string& month)
 {
   return intAsMonth(nextMonth(monthAsInt(month)));
 }

 std::string prevMonth(const std::string& month)
 {
   return intAsMonth(prevMonth(monthAsInt(month)));
 }
```